# Overlapping svg.link while clicking on line in D3.js force directed graph

Tags: jquery, d3.js

In D3.js force directed graph, while trying to click on a link the svg of the adjacent link overlaps the selected link and the needed link is not clicked. Basically,the svg draws a rectangle based on the height and width of the link and engulfs the line within it thus spanning over the adjacent lines around a particular line.
Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
bidhan@1218

Comment: Hi can you show your code?

Comment: please find the extract of the code below :

Comment: edges=[]; //array containing the links between the nodes*/
/*adding svg to the body*/

svg = d3.select(body).append("svg");

/*adding links to the graph*/
link = svg.selectAll(".link")
 .data(edges)
 .enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) {
  return "link " + d.name
 })
 .style("stroke","green")
 .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
 .on("click",function(d){
  console.log(d.id);
 })

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the overlapping issue, just might help in understanding the issue better.